# Get Variables Root-Model-Values from Virtual within Subdocument with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Aloha! Is there any way to access the Root Model from a virtual **within** a subdocument? Here is my Model-System, should make clear what I'm looking for.

The thing is that "ImageSchema" is going to be included in several places within the Root-Model with diferent "paths" to the Root-Model. "parent()" works sometimes, but not alway.

```
var ImageSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

ImageSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
  var parent = this.parent(); // Works
  var root = this.root(); // Anything like this available?
  return '/'+root.category+'/'+this.name;
});

var CombinationSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  images: [ImageSchema]
})

var RootSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    category: String,
    description: String,
    combinations: [CombinationSchema]
})
```

Thanks for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution. This is at least checking for two levels:

```
ImageSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
  var parent = this.parent()
  var root = (parent.parent ? parent.parent() : parent)
  console.log(this.parent().description +" "+ root.category + " " + this.name);
});
```